# How to avoid security warnings on https for custom webmail using iframe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, imap, webmail

I have a basic webmail client I'm writing.  The server is built around a basic node.js http server.  Pages are served over https using a valid cert from Let's Encrypt.  The message body is loaded into a sandboxed iframe via the .srcdoc attribute.

I thought loading the message into a sandboxed iframe would mitigate security warnings regarding mixed content and cross-domain content.  Unfortunately, when the content loads into the iframe, the green lock still disappears and is replaced by a security warning.

Details:  The backend uses the node.js imap-simple module to retrieve mail content from the imap server, and returns email data as a json object which is then parsed down to an array of envelope objects containing from/to/cc/bcc/date/subject/text/html entries.  Text emails are not an issue, but html emails need to be displayed as html (unless of course the user chooses no-html).

How can I safely display the html message content and avoid security warnings due to included message content that is not from my site?

Other than that it appears to be working great with the sandboxed iframes.  Cookies from message content on other sites appear to be nicely segregated to their own domains as are cookies from my site.  It appears to be nicely separating off-site data from my own sites data, scripts are disabled etc from running in the sandboxes.  If enabled for testing, a script run from inside a sandbox indeed has no access to objects outside the sandbox.

I think the warnings are appearing because the page inside the sandbox is generated from the containing page from my site, though the content references outside url's.  Obviously the sandboxed page cannot be referenced from the outside site, as it's an email.

How do I work around this to avoid security warnings?  How do other webmail clients do it?  The real problem is it makes it looks like my site is insecure to people who don't read the actual warning, or don't understand what it means (i.e. most regular users).

I was under the impression that containing the message in a sandbox would prevent the warning appearing on the containing page.

Some psuedocode to exemplify the basic structure of the page:

```
<html>
  <iframe id=mainpage>
    #docuement
      <iframe sandbox id=envelope0>
        #document
          <div>  ...email body with off-site content here  </div>
      </iframe>
  </iframe>
  <script>  //foo to get/generate html from the message(s)  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Upadate:  So I'm looking at  Roundcube, and it appears to have the same issue.  I was under the impression the sandbox specification would mitigate this.  Is this because the content is generated by a script from the webmail page coming from my site?  I've never noticed it before, but it's very obvious now.  I'm using Chrome primarily.  Is this due to one of their recent security updates?  Is there a workaround?  Gmail doesn't seem to have this problem, and they're just loading it into a div from what I'm looking at.  Interestingly, I get no such warnings on Firefox for any of these.

Comment: Gmail may be proxying the offsite content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature not a bug.

Cross domain frames will not show as secure.

> How can I safely display the html message content and avoid security warnings due to included message content that is not from my site?

You can deliver it from your site and not some other site. This will fix the SSL warning, but won't make anything "safe". If the content was dangerous, it will still be dangerous.

Comment: Yes, this is true.  I noticed that RoundCube webmail does the same thing.  Neither has this issue though on Firefox, but both do on Chrome.  Gmail however does not have this problem.  Gmail doesn't appear to use an iframe, just a div.  How do they keep the green lock?  The content is still offsite on gmail, I think.  I'm assuming Outlook webmail is the same, but don't have time today to check it out.

Comment: No, not saying it's a bug.  I understand the cross-origin deal, but how are other sites avoiding the warning?  Maybe there's something else I am missing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about gmail. All content gmail serves is from their domain(s), so it's all valid and gets the padlock.

Comment: Ah.  After digging through about a hundred nested divs, I see that the images at least in a mail on gmail are indeed proxied.  Awesome.  There's my answer, Terry.  Thank you!  Was hoping for a way with the sandbox, but it shouldn't take much to proxy the images.  Obviously will have to warn the user and make an option to show or hide the images etc.  Still need to put together a decent sanitizer anyway so maybe I'll just kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: Glad you found it! As far as the images go, you might want to see about actually examining the images for vulnerabilities. I don't remember the specifics, but it's actually possible to infect or compromise some versions of unpatched Windows with specially designed images. It was (is?) a GDI vulnerability of some sort.

Comment: Yes.  My understanding is it was possible to hide code in .jpg images (I haven't heard of other file types with this vulnerability) that would somehow get executed on older versions of IE.  This affected Windows 98 based systems, possibly earlier versions of XP.  Unfortunately there are still people clinging to old XP boxes.  I would be interested to know how the mechanics work on this though.  SVG's are possibly of some concern as they can contain and run scripts, but they are sandboxed by default if imported like a normal image (not as inline code) unless explicitly allowed otherwise.

Comment: At least that's how it's "supposed" to be... in reality nobody really knows until someone finds an exploit and either reports it, or makes problems with it. Why on earth would they make a jpg executable?  Probably related to a buffer overflow.  Buffers are incredibly important, but someone always finds a way to access portions of memory through them, even recently.  Node.js for instance had to depricate the old buffers and come up with new methods for accessing them for similar reasons.  It's a classic attack, but still finds new ways to express itself.